# Graph API + list of all sites in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been using the application credentials(Bearer token based on tenant id) from Azure ad to get the list of all the sites in the sharepoint.

I have been hitting the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=* apis in graph but getting only few subsites and not all sitelist.

But when i use the same url in graph explorer it returns all the site list.

I have all the permissions configured for the user in Azure Ad for sites.

please van any one help

Comment: If there is some demo code how to get the bearer token, it will be more helpful. Do you use the same api to get the sites?

Comment: I use the endpoint login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type : client_credentials
client_id : app id from azure
client_secrete: key from azure portal for the app
source : https:graph.microsoft.com/.default

In graph explorer it list all the sites but with the token received from the above call only tenant subsites are returned.

I learnt that for this site search i will also have to authenticate user with azure along with the app.

But for that i will need user credentials. So is there any way to get the auth token to get the site list without user password.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "search" endpoint only searches by item name.